# Elasticsearch curl post hangs and times out in a CI job

Tags: shell, elasticsearch, curl

I'm trying to upload some data to Elasticsearch via Curl in a CI job. The Curl command I believe is correct and works perfectly locally. However within the job it appears to hang and then times out after 30 seconds.

Here is the Curl command:

```
curl -u $user:$password \
      -XPOST "${HOST}${INDEX}/data" \
      -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
      -d "$json_data" \
      --max-time 30 \
      --verbose
```

Here is the verbose output:

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
 *   Trying <IP-ADDRESS>...
 * TCP_NODELAY set
 * Connected to <HOST> (<IP-ADDRESS>) port <PORT> (#0)
 * ALPN, offering h2
 * ALPN, offering http/1.1
 * successfully set certificate verify locations:
 *   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
   CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
 } [5 bytes data]
 * TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
 } [512 bytes data]
 * TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
 { [58 bytes data]
 * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
 { [3024 bytes data]
 * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
 { [556 bytes data]
 * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
 { [4 bytes data]
 * TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
 } [37 bytes data]
 * TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
 } [1 bytes data]
 * TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
 } [16 bytes data]
 * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
 { [16 bytes data]
 * SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
 * ALPN, server accepted to use h2
 * Server certificate:
 * ...
 *  SSL certificate verify ok.
 * Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
 * Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
 * Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
 } [5 bytes data]
 * Server auth using Basic with user '<USERNAME>'
 * Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x565087a74580)
 } [5 bytes data]
 > POST /elasticsearch/<INDEX>/data HTTP/2
 > Host: <HOST>
 > Authorization: Basic <KEY>
 > User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
 > Accept: */*
 > Content-Type: application/json
 > Content-Length: 13735
 >
 { [5 bytes data]
 * Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
 } [5 bytes data]
 * We are completely uploaded and fine
 { [5 bytes data]
100 13735    0     0  100 13735      0  11388  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 11388
100 13735    0     0  100 13735      0   6220  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--  6220
100 13735    0     0  100 13735      0   4280  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:--  4280
...
100 13735    0     0  100 13735      0    469  0:00:29  0:00:29 --:--:--     0
 * Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
100 13735    0     0  100 13735      0    457  0:00:30  0:00:30 --:--:--     0
 * Connection #0 to host <HOST> left intact
 curl: (28) Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
```

It looks like the host can be reached by the CI job but seems to hang for some reason. If I remove the timeout limit I get a `curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 110` error. According to the libcurl docs the 56 error code is when there is a failure receiving network data, which is strange as it’s doing a POST. Everything works fine locally, but this error is happening with every job. Any ideas?

Comment: Many things can go wrong [ [1](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl-timeouts.html)], like host with ES unreachable, or the query you are making indeed taking that long. May you please check that the host is passed correctly and that it is reachable?

Comment: Hi, I updated the post with the verbose output. It seems that it can reach the host, but still hangs for some reason.

Comment: I really don't think I can help much, but one last thing - if you change the query and do an empty request to `"${HOST}/`, does it work? Should return standard "You know, for search" JSON.